# How to Purge transaction history in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image]

It looks like we have hung transaction(s).

But we can not find it.

### show engine innodb status

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1489951061
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1489301155 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 307316
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421617768784592, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768782208, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768792936, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768801280, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768789360, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768820352, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768812008, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768810816, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768809624, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768798896, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768807240, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768791744, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768834656, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768829888, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768828696, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768823928, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768822736, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768821544, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768817968, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768816776, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768797704, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768815584, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768806048, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768790552, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768837040, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768833464, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768831080, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421617768825120, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 1489950996, ACTIVE 4 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 609, OS thread handle 140115279058688, query id 2032826 10.0.3.232 root3 Sending data
UPDATE `world_entities_entities` INNER JOIN `world_entities_entities` `zones_dig_sites` ON `world_entities_entities`.`claim_id` = `zones_dig_sites`.`id` INNER JOIN `world_entities_entities` `regions_dig_sites` ON `zones_dig_sites`.`claim_id` = `regions_dig_sites`.`id` SET `world_entities_entities`.`state` = 'used' WHERE `world_entities_entities`.`type` IN ('World::Entities::Map::Poi::DigSite') AND `regions_dig_sites`.`claim_id` = 3406537 AND (world_entities_entities.created_at < '2018-10-25 15:24:07.462581') AND (world_entities_entities.state <> 'used')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 4 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 843 page no 119087 n bits 104 index PRIMARY of table `pgr_production`.`world_entities_entities` trx id 1489950996 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
------------------
---TRANSACTION 1489950595, ACTIVE 31 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1135, OS thread handle 140115282519808, query id 2027747 10.0.3.230 root3 updating
UPDATE `world_entities_entities` SET `updated_at` = '2018-10-26 15:23:40', `soft_produced_at` = '2018-10-26 15:23:39' WHERE `world_entities_entities`.`id` = 4720483
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 1489950595, sees < 1489948670
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 31 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 843 page no 162685 n bits 104 index PRIMARY of table `pgr_production`.`world_entities_entities` trx id 1489950595 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
------------------
---TRANSACTION 1489950370, ACTIVE 44 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 117, OS thread handle 140115390269184, query id 2024932 10.0.3.231 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `users_users`.`session_count` = 20 WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 37077
---TRANSACTION 1489949929, ACTIVE 72 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 153, OS thread handle 140115293169408, query id 2020201 10.0.3.232 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `users_users`.`session_count` = 15 WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 1174116
---TRANSACTION 1489949898, ACTIVE 77 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
125223 lock struct(s), heap size 11346128, 6310586 row lock(s), undo log entries 1185367
MySQL thread id 1583, OS thread handle 140115391334144, query id 2019166 10.0.3.229 root3 Sending data
INSERT INTO `world_entities_entities_new`  (SELECT * FROM world_entities_entities order by id asc limit 5000000 offset 5000000)
---TRANSACTION 1489949751, ACTIVE 82 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 755, OS thread handle 140115291305728, query id 2017902 10.0.3.230 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `migration_version` = 19, `updated_at` = '2018-10-26 15:22:49' WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 1140559
---TRANSACTION 1489949380, ACTIVE 101 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 93, OS thread handle 140115390535424, query id 2013062 10.0.3.229 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `users_users`.`session_count` = 16 WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 130123
---TRANSACTION 1489948860, ACTIVE 127 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 114, OS thread handle 140115295033088, query id 2007219 10.0.3.231 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `users_users`.`session_count` = 367 WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 1146835
---TRANSACTION 1489948670, ACTIVE 137 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 90, OS thread handle 140115296896768, query id 2004586 10.0.3.229 root3 updating
UPDATE `users_users` SET `users_users`.`session_count` = 69 WHERE `users_users`.`id` = 1174137
```

### show processlist

We killed all sleep processes in this list

### Other

We stopped mysql, rebooted whole server. But `transaction history length` grows

Any idea how to stop growing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Transaction history purged in `30h`.

We found initiator.

It was `DELETE from big_table where id in <arr_length_1000>`

And just an idea that DB tried to recalculate indexes for this table `30h`

Answer (score 2):

According to this [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/05/08/chasing-a-hung-transaction-in-mysql-innodb-history-length-strikes-back/) (you probably have read it), root cause can be application code holding connections and don't release. In addition, you might also getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction..." error message.

It looks like killing sleeping connections didn't help with the history length in your case because the graph kept going up. But the article also mentioned enable the `events_statements_history` which is worth considering.

If your query using many joins you might also want to look into `table_open_cache`

See a list of lock tables `show open tables where in_use > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Don't walk through a table via `OFFSET`.

```
limit  5000000 offset 5000000
```

It has to step over 5M rows, then grab the next 5M.  If you next have `limit 5M offset 10M`, etc., then the processing gets slower and slower.

Instead, "remember where you left off" and start from there.  Also, don't use chunks bigger than 1K; 5M is *much to big* to avoid nasty problem like you are hitting.

Get the next stopping point ($z) via

```
SELECT id FROM tbl
    WHERE id >= $a
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1000, 1;
```

Then do

```
INSERT ... SELECT ... 
    WHERE id >= $a
      AND ic <  $z
    ORDER BY id
```

Note: no LIMIT nor OFFSET needed in the second query.  For more details on this technique, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).  Also [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).